# Git email hook to include commit message and changed files

Tags: git, heroku, git-svn, githooks

I set up the email hook for git in heroku. However, all i get is the message that something is pushed - i need both the commit message and the modified files.

```
#what i now get in the email:
noreply@heroku.com to me, hermantamas

xxx@gmail.com deployed app
```

---

```
#what i need:
noreply@heroku.com to me, hermantamas

xxx@gmail.com deployed app:

"home page is now working"
Changed:
- index.html
- javascript.js
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would mean modifying the [Heorku email hook](http://docs.heroku.com/deploy-hooks#toc) directly to add some of [those git log options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230084/how-to-have-git-log-show-filenames-like-svn-log-v) (`git log --name-status`, `git log --name-only`, `git log --stat` or `git whatchanged`)

But since you may not have the possibility to change directly the hook script, you still can add one [Heroku variable](http://docs.heroku.com/deploy-hooks#customizing-messages) when defining said mail hook.

> **git_log**: log of commits between this deploy and the last

```
$ heroku addons:add deployhooks:email \
    recipient=me@example.com \
    subject="Myapp Deployed" \
    body="{{user}} deployed app: {{git_log}}"
Adding deployhooks:email to myapp...Done.
```