# (Heroku/GIT) Comments added to commit command not appearing in activity

Tags: facebook, git, heroku, commit

Me and a friend are creating an app for facebook. So to keep organized, when we do something and push it to heroku, we add a comment to the commit command such as:

```
git commit -am "changed logo"
```

The problem we're having is that in the heroku website, in the activity log, we get messages like:

```
v34 ************@gmail.com: Deploy ce43e3a less than a minute ago
```

We used to have the comments appear instead of the "Deploy weirdcode"... What can we do to make that happen again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to [customizing the message of one of the Heroku Deploy hooks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks#customizing-messages).
I remember having done so more than 2 years ago in "[Git email hook to include commit message and changed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406069/git-email-hook-to-include-commit-message-and-changed-files)".

> It’s possible to use variables when defining the message, title or subject of any deploy hook attribute.

```
git_log
```

> log of commits between this deploy and the last