# How do I know the list of commits / changes before I push

Tags: git

git status shows that I have 2 commits

```
# On branch production
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/production' by 2 commits.
#
```

but git diff shows nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git diff` doesn't, by default, show you anything from previous commits. You should use `git log` for that. To show the last two commits, use `git log -2`.

To compare commits with each other using diff, the syntax is `git diff commit1 commit2`. For example, to show you all the changes that occurred between two commits ago and now, type `git diff HEAD^2 HEAD`.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, to show commits present in HEAD, but not origin/production:

```
git log origin/production..
```

With filenames information (from [How to have git log show filenames like svn log -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230084/how-to-have-git-log-show-filenames-like-svn-log-v) ):

```
git log --stat origin/production..
git log --name-status origin/production..
git log --name-only origin/production..
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use the following to see my commit tree:

```
$ gitk
```

Without arguments `git diff` only shows the difference between your actual changes and the actual commit, meaning everything you changed since your last `git checkout` or `git commit`.

Comment: I think answer from @Vonc is a more reliable one.

Also please not that `gitk` is not always guaranteed to be available.