# How to show changed file name only with 'git log'

Tags: git

Is it able to show changed **file name** only with `git log`?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Bash function to find all Git commits in which a file (whose name matches a regex) has *changed*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119379/bash-function-to-find-all-git-commits-in-which-a-file-whose-name-matches-a-rege/28120305)

Answer (score 281, accepted):

I use

```
git log --name-only
```

or

```
git log --name-only --oneline
```

for short.

Comment: The `--name-only` argument will work even with the `git show` command.

Answer (score 98):

I guess you could use the `--name-only` flag. Something like:

```
git log 73167b96 --pretty="format:" --name-only
```

I personally use `git show` for viewing files changed in a commit:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only 73167b96
```

(73167b96 could be any commit/tag name)

Comment: this solution is pretty nice to ONLY have the list of files without author, date or commit message info

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for - but it does include the commit message for me - as I wanted to pipe the output, that wasn't optimal.

Comment: super, thanks a lot! All i now need to open all changed files in last commit is
```alias gshsubl='git show --name-only --pretty="format:" --name-only|xargs subl'
```

Answer (score 46):

I stumbled in here looking for a similar answer without the "git log" restriction. The answers here didn't give me what I needed but this did so I'll add it in case others find it useful:

```
git diff --name-only
```

You can also couple this with standard commit pointers to see what has changed since a particular commit:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~3
git diff --name-only develop
git diff --name-only 5890e37..ebbf4c0
```

This succinctly provides file names *only* which is great for scripting. For example:

```
git diff --name-only develop | while read changed_file; do echo "This changed from the develop version: $changed_file"; done

#OR

git diff --name-only develop | xargs tar cvf changes.tar
```

Comment: Also works with `git log --name-only`

Comment: And it works with `git show --name-only HEAD` to see the files changed in the latest commit.

Answer (score 39):

This gives almost what you need:

```
git log --stat --oneline
```

The commit ID and a short one line still remains, followed by a list of changed files by that commit.

Answer (score 24):

Now I use the following to get the list of changed files my current branch has, comparing it to master (the compare-to branch is easily changed):

```
git log --oneline --pretty="format:" --name-only master.. | awk 'NF' | sort -u
```

---

Before, I used to rely on this:

```
git log --name-status <branch>..<branch> | grep -E '^[A-Z]\b' | sort -k 2,2 -u
```

which outputs a list of files only and their state (added, modified, deleted):

```
A   foo/bar/xyz/foo.txt
M   foo/bor/bar.txt
...
```

The `-k2,2` option for sort, makes it sort by file path instead of the type of change (A, M, D,).

Comment: This is literally the only answer that actually provides the answer to the question of "file name only".

Comment: Short addition: this command will also shows that have been added and subsequently renamed or removed in the same branch. These files may no longer exist.

Answer (score 12):

If you need **just** file names, like:

```
dir/subdir/file1.txt
dir/subdir2/file2.sql
dir2/subdir3/file6.php
```

(which I use as a source for **tar** command), you will also need to filter out commit messages.

In order to do this, I use the following command:

```
git log --name-only --oneline | grep -v '.{7} '
```

The [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) command excludes (the `-v` parameter) every line which starts with seven symbols (which is the length of my Git hash for the `git log` command) followed by space. So it filters out every Git `hash message` line and leave only lines with file names.

One useful improvement is to append [`uniq`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq) to remove duplicate lines, so it will look as follows:

```
git log --name-only --oneline | grep -v '.{7} ' | uniq
```

Comment: In OSX bash shell, its necessary to put backslashes before the brackets. I also added the line start matching and space matcher. "git show --name-only --oneline | grep -v '^.\{7\}\s'"