# How to list all the committed files by a user in a branch?

Tags: git

I know there's a git command to list all the commits by a user and number of days as below,

```
git log --since=15.days --author="Vijin Paulraj"
```

However, that will only return the list of commits done by the user with hash. But I don't see any commands to list only the file names.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207414/how-to-show-changed-file-name-only-with-git-log for starters

Comment: `git log --name-only --since=15.days --author="Vijin Paulraj"` - is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass to git log option `--name-only` it will show only names of changed files. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: yeah I tried `git log --name-only --since=15.days --author="Vijin Paulraj"`. It's working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get file list in a specific interval of time
**git log --name-only --author="authar name" --since='Date From' --until='date To'**