# Getting files committed and number of lines changed

Tags: git

I am able to get the files changes and lines affected along with a lot of other stuff by this command

```
git log -p -1 --stat --color=never
```

But I just need file names and no of lines affected, how would I get that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```
git diff --stat --summary -M HEAD HEAD~
```

it outputs the stats in the same format as a `git merge` does.

Or without color for two other commits, e.g.

```
git diff --stat --summary --no-color -M  6c1dea3 e8f4b44
```

or only the staging area

```
git diff --cached --stat --summary -M
```

Comment: That looks closer to what the OP is after. I didn't interpreted the "no of lines affected" as "number of lines affected" (I initially thought the OP did *not* want the lines displayed!). So +1.

Comment: yup, I should have put "no." at least. but this is kinda what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

If you can ignore the blank lines, as mentioned in "[How to have `git log` show filenames like `svn log -v`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583922/6309)", you can use:

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format: <branch name>
```

Comment: umm this not what i was looking for, the command in the question gives output like 
`filenamewithfullpath.cpp  |  lines changed` along with commit message diff etc... i just want `filenamewithfullpath.cpp  |  lines changed`

Comment: @tejashs Strange: I don't see any "lines changed" in the output of that command. Only `filenamewithfullpath.cpp`.