# Using git log to display files changed during merge

Tags: git, merge, git-log

I’m executing the following command:

```
git log --name-only –pretty="format:%H %s" -- *.sql --grep="JIRA-154"
```

which returns results in the format:

```
[commitid1] [comment]
path/to/file1/file1.sql
path/to/file2/file2.sql
path/to/file3/file3.sql

[commitid2] [comment]
path/to/file2/file2.sql
path/to/file4/file4.sql
```

The output is redirected to a file and the format is exactly what I’m looking for, however merge commits are a problem. The files that have been changed as part of a merge are never listed. Instead I end up with something like the following:

```
[commitid3] [merge comment]
[commitid4] [comment]
path/to/file3/file3.sql
```

I’ve obviously misunderstood something here because I expect to see the files that changed during the merge listed. Is there a way to include these files in the output?

Comment: `--grep="JIRA-154"` is expected to be placed before `-- *.sql`, or it has no effect. A merge commit itself does not get any file involved.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that @ElpieKay - I hadn't realised and it does make a difference.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Try adding the `-m` option to the `git log` options.  This makes Git "split" each merge, so that it will diff the merge *twice*, once against each parent.  Without this or some other similar option, `git log` finds the merges but then does not even look inside them at all.

Also, as [ElpieKay commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801342/using-git-log-to-display-files-changed-during-merge/37802111?noredirect=1#comment63069212_37801342), you need to put the `--grep=<regexp>` before the `--`.  It may also be a good idea to write `"*.sql"`, i.e., with quotes, to prevent your shell from expanding the asterisk itself (the details vary from one shell to another and depend on whether there are any `*.sql` files in your current working directory).

#### Long version

As [Tim Biegeleisen said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801468/1256452), the problem stems from the nature of a merge commit.

Normally, to show you what changed in a commit, Git runs a simple `git diff parent self`, where *`parent`* and *`self`* are the commit's parent, and the commit itself, respectively.  Both `git log` and `git show` do this, in slightly different ways and under slightly different circumstances.  The most obvious is that `git show` defaults to showing a diff every time, but `git log` only does a diff when given `-p` or one of the various diff control options such as `--name-only`.

#### Merges are different

A *merge commit* is a commit with two<sup>1</sup> parents.  This means that `git log` and `git show` would have to run *two* `git diff` commands.<sup>2</sup>  And in fact, `git show` does run two diffs, but then—by default—turns them into a [*combined diff*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_combined_diff_format), which [shows only those files whose merge-commit version differs from *both* parents](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_diff_format_for_merges).  But for whatever reason,<sup>3</sup> `git log` does not do this by default.

Even when `git log` is showing diffs, though, it behaves particularly oddly (I might even say badly) on merges.  While `git log -p` or `git log --name-status` runs a (single) diff on a regular commit, it *does not run the diff at all* on a commit with multiple visible parents, *unless* you force it to.

Using `-m` by itself always works.  This flag essentially tells `git log` (and `git show`) to *break up* a merge into multiple separate "virtual commits".  That is, if commit *M* is a merge with parents *P1* and *P2*, then—for the purpose of the diff at least—Git acts as though there was a commit *MP1* with parent *P1*, and a second commit *MP2* with parent *P2*.  You get *two* diffs (and two commit IDs in the diff headers).

Adding `--first-parent` tells `git log` to ignore the second (and any additional) parent of a merge, which leaves it with just one parent.  This means `git log` won't follow the side branch *at all*.  Hence you can use `-m --first-parent`, provided you're not interested in histories stemming from the other sides of merges.  That gets you a single diff against just the *first* parent, instead of one diff per parent.

(Which parent is *first?*  Well, it's the one that was your `HEAD` when you ran `git merge`.  That's normally the "main line" of commits, i.e., the ones "on your branch".  But if your group uses `git pull` casually, you probably do *not* want to ignore the other side of merges, as `git pull` turns other people's main-line work into ["foxtrot merges"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452) of small side branches.)

#### Combined diffs, again

Besides `-m`, you can supply `-c` or `--cc` (note that `-c` has one dash while `--cc` has two<sup>4</sup>) to `git log` to get it to produce a combined diff, just like `git show`.  But, as with all combined diffs, this ignores files that match up between the merge commit and either parent.  That is, given the same merge *M* again, this time Git compares *M* vs *P1*, and *M* vs *P2*.  For any file *F* where *M:F* is the same as either *P1:F* or *P2:F*, Git shows nothing at all.

As it turns out, this is usually what you want.  If file *F* in commit *M* matches file *F* in one of the two parent commits, that means the file *came from* that parent.  The fact that *F* in *P1* may not match *F* in *P2* is usually not interesting: any change in *F* in either *P1* or *P2* is probably a result of some *earlier* change in history, and that's where we should take note of it, rather than at merge *M*.

That is the logic behind combined diffs, anyway.  It's not applicable in all circumstances, which is why `-m` exists: to "split up" the merge into its constituent parts.

---

<sup>1</sup>Two or more, actually, but "more" is unusual; most merge commits have exactly two parents.  A merge commit with more than two parents is called an *octopus merge*.

<sup>2</sup>Both `git log` and `git show` have most of `git diff` built in to them, so that they do not actually have to run additional commands, but it works out the same either way.

<sup>3</sup>I don't know the reason, and I only learned of this particular behavior when I went through the `git log` source, trying to explain why `git log --name-status` had not shown something.

<sup>4</sup>This is because `--cc` is a *long* option, and in GNU option parsing, all long options like `name-only` or `cc` get *two* dashes, while all *short* (one letter) options like `p` get *one* dash.

Comment: Very helpful information and explanation. However, for the short-on-time help-seeker, I would add a "tl;dr add `-m`" in the beginning of your answer.

Comment: @Martin: perhaps; but `-m` output tends to be long, and if you're not aware that it makes one diff *per parent*, it will also be very confusing. I guess I can stick that in there too, let's see how that works :-)

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are observing this behavior is that in the case of a merge commit there are *two* sets of changed files, one coming from each parent.  One option here would be to use the `--first-parent -m` options when running your `git log`:

```
git log --name-only --grep="JIRA-154" --first-parent -m –-pretty="format:%H %s" -- "*.sql"
```

This will tell Git to focus onlg on the main branch into which the merge is happening, showing the set of files for this commit only.

Check [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for the documentation and [here](http://marcgg.com/blog/2015/08/04/git-first-parent-log/) for a great blog post.

Comment: While experimenting just now (based on Martin's request for a TL;DR in my answer), I discovered that `git log --first-parent` doesn't really work right (in my opinion): it first sees that the merge commit *is* a merge commit and disables any diffs, *then* does the "first parent" graph chop, and then, having marked the merge to be skipped, does no diffing anyway. Combining `--first-parent` with `-m` works and does the right thing. Note that `--first-parent` interacts much better with `git show`.

Comment: @torek Please edit if this answer still have any validity.  If not let me know and I can delete it.