# How to see which files were changed in last commit

Tags: git

In this commit message, it says that 2 files have been changed.

```
$ git commit -m "fixed .gitignore"
[master c30afbe] fixed .gitignore
 Committer: Sahand Zarrinkoub <sahandzarrinkoub@n133-p41.eduroam.kth.se>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the
following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit
your configuration file:

    git config --global --edit

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 2 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
```

This is a little surprising for me. I thought I'd only staged one file to be changed. Now, I'd like to see which files have been changed and how. What is the way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `git status`?

Comment: You could also try `git diff`

Comment: What command did you use to get this message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have git log show filenames like svn log -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230084/how-to-have-git-log-show-filenames-like-svn-log-v)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit)

Comment: @Lix , @Ron neither of your comments address this, `since` the last commit and `in` the last commit are two different things..

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can try `git log --stat`

Here `--stat` will display the number of insertions and deletions to each file altered by each commit.

**Example:** Below commit added 67 lines to the `Demo.java` file and removed 38 lines:

```
commit f2a238924456ca1d4947662928218a06d39068c3
Author: X <X@example.com>
Date: Fri May 21 15:17:28 2020 -0500
Add a new feature
Demo.java | 105 ++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------
1 file changed, 67 insertion(+), 38 deletions(-)
```

Comment: This command will show only the last commit stats: `git log --stat -1`

Comment: `git log -1 --pretty=%H` only shows the commit hash

Answer (score 215):

Get all changed files in the last commit

```
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, thank you @Robin He!

Comment: OP: "Now, I'd like to see which files have been changed **and how**" ...so no, this answer is only adressing half of what's asked for.

Comment: You can use `^` (parent commit) operator too: `git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD^`.

Comment: You can try `git show --oneline --name-only --pretty='' HEAD`

Comment: `git show --name-only` is a quick way to "see which files were changed in last commit".

Answer (score 33):

You can do this in a number of ways. This is what I came up with without looking into docs.

```
$ git log -1 --name-only

commit 3c60430b752bca26bd3c80604df87ffb2ae358 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Name Surname <name.surname@email.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 2 18:17:25 2018 +0200

    Example commit

.gitignore
README
src/main.c
```

Or:

```
$ git log -1 --name-only --oneline

commit 3c60430 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Example commit
.gitignore
README
src/main.c
```

Or:

```
$ git log -1 --stat --oneline

commit 3c60430 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Example commit
.gitignore |  2 ++
README     |  8 ++++++++
src/main.c | 12 ++++++++++++
3 files changed, 22 insertions(+)
```

Or (thanks to [Bencho Naut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18068312/bencho-naut)):

```
$ git log -1 --name-only --pretty=''

.gitignore
README
src/main.c
```

Comment: right to the point, simple command, thank you

Comment: The last command you show `git log -1 --stat --oneline` fits best to my needs, since it also displays the commit hash, list of files ... and also I can show more commits: `git log -3 --stat --oneline`

Comment: Oh thanks my dear `git log -1 --oneline --name-only --pretty='' HEAD`

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Nitin Bisht's answer you can use the following:

```
git log -1 --stat --oneline
```

It will show condensed information on which files were changed in last commit. Naturally, instead of "-1" there can by any number of commits specified to show files changed in last "-n" commits.

Also you can skip merged commits passing "--no-merges" flag:

```
git log -1 --stat --oneline --no-merges
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `diff-tree`

`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commit_hash>`

Comment: This command only list the top directory which were changed in that commit

Comment: adding -r after diff-tree should fix that

Comment: you can also use `--diff-filter=M` to look specifically at which ones were modified (vs. added/renamed/deleted/etc.)

Answer (score 5):

```
git log  // this will give you the hash-code 
git show hash-code
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the preferred one for me

```
git show --name-status --pretty=""
```

Or if I only want the names of the files:

```
git show --name-only --pretty=""
```

Other things like `--stat`  are also available with  `git show`.

Answer (score 0):

`git show --name-only`

This is simplest form. It is the similar to `git show` (which shows the diff of the last commit), except it shows the filenames that were changed, instead of the diff.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked "Now, I'd like to see which files have been changed *and how*".

`git log -p -1` will do this.

It will show the files changed, and their diff.

```
commit 688459646aa8f32a8xxxxxxxxxxxxee9034e91 (HEAD -> test)
Author: xxx <xxx@xxx.xxx>
Date:   Tue Jan 2 20:52:14 2024 -0500

    Relative output needs relative input

diff --git a/internal/adapter/handlebars/handlebars_test.go b/internal/adapter/handlebars/handlebars_test.go
index 6a942c0..373cd7a 100644
--- a/internal/adapter/handlebars/handlebars_test.go
+++ b/internal/adapter/handlebars/handlebars_test.go
@@ -238,6 +238,8 @@ func TestFormatDateHelper(t *testing.T) {
        testString(t, "{{format-date now 'timestamp'}}", context, "200911172034")
        testString(t, "{{format-date now 'timestamp-unix'}}", context, "1258490098")
        testString(t, "{{format-date now 'cust: %Y-%m'}}", context, "cust: 2009-11")
+       year := time.Now().UTC().Year() - 14
+       context = map[string]interface{}{"now": time.Date(year, 11, 17, 20, 34, 58, 651387237, time.UTC)}
        testString(t, "{{format-date now 'elapsed'}}", context, "14 years ago")
 }
```