# How to detect if changes are made to files outside particular folder in git

Tags: git, github

I have one git repository on github. The scenario is like this : In this repository, there is one folder called `files`. My collaborators very frequently make changes to this directory. I also have `Dockerfile` in this repo. I only want to build the docker image again if anything outside of `files` folder change. If not, I want to use the prebuilt docker image. This building and using docker images is done in Jenkins. Since directory `files` is changed very frequently, I don't want to build my docker image every time this directory changes.

How can I determine if in any commit, the changed files are in this directory or not?

Currently, I use a pygithub script, to make API calls to github, however, this is very slow, and also I have the repository already checked out. I wanted to know if I can achieve this using git commands. If so, this could be done very fast.

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853177/how-to-see-which-files-were-changed-in-last-commit). There they tell you how to get a list of changed files, from there you'll have to build your own parsing and testing script to fire the build or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your local clone:

```
git show --format= --name-only -- ':!files/'
```

`git show --format= --name-only` lists all changed files in the current commit (`HEAD`) compared to the previous commit (parent).

`':!files/'` excludes directory `files` from the list. See [`pathspec`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) in git glossary.

If you want to list files changed between any commits use `git diff --name-only`. Example :

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~5 HEAD -- ':!files/'
```

for the last 5 commits.