# How to find added files between 2 commits?

Tags: git

Suppose I `touch file`,then `git add -A`,`git commit -a` several times.
Then I have commits like:

```
b6913186abd9259f8e3e18f778cbb0743e431a98 commit3
a3309719f0fcee236b794fcb053ee252c762bbac commit2
4fe5675b900d7e20ec94784ad1fb5580581564ce commit1
```

When I want to know which files added from `commit1` to `commit3`,how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see the changes between two commits without commits in-between?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191282/how-to-see-the-changes-between-two-commits-without-commits-in-between)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have git log show filenames like svn log -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230084/how-to-have-git-log-show-filenames-like-svn-log-v)

Comment: @OSH,@EncryptedWatermelon,No! changed file may means deleted files.I am looking for the new added file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the files added between your `commit1` and `commit3` with

```
 git diff b69131..4fe567 --name-status | grep ^A
```

The `--name-status` parameter will print all the files changed between the two commits, with every file changed in a new line which starts with a certain character. If this caracter is *A* means the file was added, *D* for deleted file, *M* for modified, *R* for renamed... so we can use `grep` to filter it.

You can find in the [git-diff docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) all the options you could use to filter.

---

**Update:** look at the comment below by @jthill, it's better for the clean usage of `--name-only` and `--diff-filter`.

Comment: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A b691..4fe5`