# How I can detect what files has been modified manually after composer install?

Tags: php, git

Many coleagues of mine after `composer install` they manually edit files and `git commit` `./vendor` alongside with their changes.

In my case I see as a bad practice but makes the app work. Therefore I want to detect what files has changed. The idea is that manual changes are either single-file commits or commits that have number files at `./vendor` < total number of files in `./vendor`

How I can do this?

Comment: I fear no man but those who code in the vendor directory. Seriously tho, maybe git log your vendor directory and check what changed ?

Comment: This is a little bit off-topic but `vendor/` shouldn't be commited. You may commit `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, ignore `vendor/` and apply changes to it with something like https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches

Comment: Either they make sure to split the incoming vendored code commits and the their-own-modifications commits or they don't. There is no version control practice to untangle that after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

Never edit files inside `/vendor` as it can easily lead to bugs, especially if that dependency is used in other libraries.

Simple answer - fork that dependency and use your own fork in `composer.json`.

Please refer to following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498519/how-to-require-a-fork-with-composer) for full explanation:

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/desyllas/monolog"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-fix"
    }
}
```

Comment: If only they could hear me. Always ending in piece of s****

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Another approach (but very dependant on what actual is being changed) is to extend library class with own code. Composer even allows to re-define where source class is located

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deal with repository that contains `./vendor/` changes in it and

> Therefore I want to detect what files has changed.

Your need is justified IMO.

### Solution 1

```bash
git log --name-status
```

Gives besides typical info also information about changed files (their paths)

### Solution 2

If you want to narrow result to only files that are changed inside vendor dir use `-- ./vendor` as the suffix:

```bash
git log --name-status -- ./vendor
```

### Solution 3

Similar to the ones above but gives a fancy indicator of number of changes inside the file.

```bash
git log --stat
```

### Solution 4

this way you'll get paths to files:

```bash
git log --name-only --oneline
```

taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70180240/1174405)

you may limit its output:

```bash
git log --name-only --oneline HEAD^..HEAD
```

to see diffenece between tip of your branch (HEAD) and one commit before it (HEAD^) or just put instead of them `commit1sha..commit2sha`

### Solution 5

This command focuses more on paths and their modification status (M = Modified, A = Added, etc) instead of log messages:

```bash
git log --name-status --pretty='' commit1..commit2
```

If you want to get only paths (without mod status) and optionally remove duplicates see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77017382/1174405) - you may also like other answers in that thread.